# Using two dropdown selections to determine equation used

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, dropdown, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google spreadsheet and I want the equation to change based on two dropdown menu selections.  Dropdown selections are:

- Dropdown 1: BA, MF, SWT
- Dropdown 2: Execution, Guardian, TDM

Now, I want the equation to look at both dropdown selections, then use the appropriate equation.  So far I have the following

```
=IF(C1="ba", if(E1="execution", EQUATION#1)), if(C1="ba", if(E1="guardian",  EQUATION#2))))
```

The above works to calculation Equation#1 when the first two IF statements are met, however the above does not work when the 3rd and 4th IF statements are met, it simply shows 'FALSE' in the cell instead of performing Equation#2.  Please note: I removed the equation to try and keep it simple but can provide more info to anyone that is curious.  Any help or suggestions to achieve my goal will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
=IF((C1="BA") *(E1="Guardian"),  "EQUATION 1", 
 IF((C1="BA") *(E1="Execution"), "EQUATION 2",
 IF((C1="BA") *(E1="TDM"),       "EQUATION 3",
 IF((C1="MF") *(E1="Guardian"),  "EQUATION 4",
 IF((C1="MF") *(E1="Execution"), "EQUATION 5",
 IF((C1="MF") *(E1="TDM"),       "EQUATION 6",
 IF((C1="SWF")*(E1="Guardian"),  "EQUATION 7",
 IF((C1="SWF")*(E1="Execution"), "EQUATION 8",
 IF((C1="SWF")*(E1="TDM"),       "EQUATION 9", )))))))))
```

[image: 0]